# Zeros of Dirichlet eta function

Tags: number-theory

Is it correct to argue the following?

The Dirichlet eta function can be divided into the real term and the imaginary term
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}n^{-x-iy}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} n^{-x}\cos(y\ln(n)) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x} i \sin(y\ln(n)),\\  x\in (0,1), y\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
The Dirichlet eta function is equal to zero when the real term and the imaginary term are both equal to zero.

The Riemann functional equation can be adopted for the Dirichlet eta function
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}=2^{s}\pi^{s-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma (1-s)\frac{1-2^{1-s}}{1-2^{s}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} n^{-(1-s)},
$$
$$
s = x+iy, 1-s = 1-(x+iy)=1-x-iy.
$$
The fuctional equation represents pairs of zeros symmetrical to the origin of coordinates. Each zero is accompanied by its complex conjugate.
$$
s = x-iy, 1-s = 1-(x-iy)=1-x+iy.
$$
Thus zeros in $x\in (0, \frac{1}{2})\vee (\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ should occur in pairs symmetrically to the line at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

That implies that the Dirichlet eta function is equal to zero when the real term and the imaginary term are both equal to zero at $x$ and at $1-x$ for any real $y$ and $-y$.

As the cosine function is even and the sine function is odd, it applies
$$
\cos(y\ln(n))=\cos(-y\ln(n)),
-\sin(y\ln(n))=\sin(-y\ln(n)).
$$
In addition, it holds
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n)).
$$
Then the following equations should be kept
\begin{align}
& (1)\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n)) = 0,\\
& (2)\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} n^{-x}\cos(y\ln(n)) = 0,\\
& (3)\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} n^{x-1}\sin(y\ln(n)) = 0,\\
& (4)\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} n^{x-1}\cos(y\ln(n)) = 0.
\end{align}
From the functional equation and the existence of complex conjugate solutions, it follows that the equations (1) and (2) are both satisfied only if the equations (3) and (4) are both satisfied. That implies that only $x=1-x$ solves the equations (1) - (4).

Therefore there is no more than one $x\in (0,1)$ (and this one equals to $x=\frac{1}{2}$) for any real $y$ for which the real term and the imaginary term of the Dirichlet eta function are both equal to zero.

Comment: And your question is ...

Comment: You should edit the text to make it a question - like "Is it correct to argue ..."

Comment: @MarkBennet It seems like Martin is asking if this is a simple proof of the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that the eta function has no zeros for the region $0<\Re(z)<1$?

Comment: @jjagmath I believe the question is does this prove there's no more than one zero of $\eta(x+i y)$ for any given $x$ where $0<x<1\land y\in\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. along any horizontal line in the critical strip) which implies the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: @Steven Clark You are right. I have been thinking about the topic a little bit. However, I see the Greg's answer below. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @StevenClark My point was that the OP didn't state the proposition to prove.

Comment: Please don't dramatically change the question statement, especially now that an answer has been accepted.

Comment: @GregMartin I am sorry. The answer helped me to develop the topic further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is not valid.

It is true that a positive linear combination of increasing functions is increasing, and that a positive linear combination of decreasing functions is decreasing.

It is not true that a linear combination of monotonic functions is necessarily monotonic.

Comment: A complex combination of monotonic functions in the sense of this question can indeed only have at most one zero for each value of $y$. The validity depends on the claim that real and imaginary parts are monotonic in $x$. Which looks unlikely to me, but I know nothing about the eta function.

Comment: The justification by monotonic functions was removed.